# A sequence of continuous functions

Tags: sequence-of-function

> There exist a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, but
>
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_n(x)dx \neq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$

solution I tried-

as we know that if sequence of continuous function $f_n$ converges to a fucntion $f$ over a given interval $[a,\infty)$ then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^{\infty}f_n(x)dx = \int_{a }^{\infty}f(x)dx$$
so in the above question they replace the $a$ with $-\infty$ does it effects the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is not correct.  Actually, for this one,  you find a counterexample for the existence.

Consider $$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n(1+\vert x \vert)}$$ Now try to complete the details!

Comment: does it only work when interval is compact?

Comment: The indefinite integral is divergent here

Comment: Oh...you mean ..about original problem?  Yes, for compact intervals , limit of the integral equals integral of the limit